# Responsive datatables details icon conditional formatting

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, datatables

I just want to change color of detail symbol color when datatable is collapsed on specific condition. Spend soo much time to do it

here is my code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Heading1</th>
                            <th>Heading2</th>
                            .
                            .
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                           @{ 
                            int i = 1;
                            }
                           @foreach(var item in foo)
                            {
                            <tr>
                            <td>Data1</td>
                            <td>Data2</td>
                            .
                            .
                               @if(item.cond == true)
                               {
<style>
table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed > tbody > tr:nth-child(@i) > td:first-child:before {
background-color: red;
}
</style>
                               }
                               else
                               {
<style>
table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed > tbody > tr:nth-child(@i) > td:first-child:before {
background-color: white;
color: blue;
}
</style>
                               }
                            </tr>
                            i++
                            }
                    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

looking work but when i'm try to search something or change the show entries count, it fails.

[image]

seems my pseudo class is fails on changes.

my question is;
how can i select the td without nth-child() or how can i asign this style to my td with id selector ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add special class to `tr` element when certain condition occurs. For example:

```
@foreach(var item in foo)
{
   @if(item.cond == true){
     <tr class="row-highlight">
   } else {
     <tr>
   }
```

Then just use these CSS rules:

```
<style>
table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed > tbody > tr > td:first-child:before {
   background-color: white;
}
table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed > tbody > tr.row-highlight > td:first-child:before {
   background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you soo much !